# How to toolbar`s button to be focused in ExtJS 4.2?

Tags: javascript, extjs

There is application in ExtJS and I am endeavouring to manage application without mouse. Some things is done, but I have no idea with toolbars button. Toolbars button cannot be focused. Although in application enabled *Ext.FocusManager*

```
Ext.FocusManager.enable(true);
```

What have to do to fix this problem?

```
var nav3 = Ext.create('Ext.util.KeyNav', Ext.getBody(), {

            "enter" : function(){
                var el = Ext.FocusManager.focusedCmp;
                if( el.getXType() == 'menuToolbar' ){
                    console.log(el.items.items[0]);
                    el.items.items[0].focus();
                }


            },
            scope : this
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code. First of all, `Ext.create` takes two arguments, you pass three. Thus the class created cannot work.

`el.items.items[0]` cannot work. Rather use `el.down('button')` to tell what component you want to select.

Your code should probably look like this

```
var nav3 = Ext.create('Ext.util.KeyNav', {
    target: Ext.getBody(),
    enter: function(){
        var el = Ext.FocusManager.focusedCmp;
        if( el.getXType() == 'menuToolbar' ){
            console.log(el.down('button')); 
            el.down('button') .focus();
        }
    }, 
    scope: this
});
```

Comment: But Ext.create with 3 params works finely, I got this code from extjs documentation "keyboard navigation". You can check it here http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/guide/keyboard_nav